# autopunch or auto coding base on the response

Tags: javascript, node-modules, nodes

Hi i am only a beginner in coding or programming.

My problem is that i want to auto punch or auto code hD1_1 base in D1_1.

if D1_1 = 1 it will auto code this number "1923"

This is my code written below in Node.JS

var age = respondent.data('D1_1');
if( age == 1) { respondent.data('hD1_1','1923');    }

done();

Thank you for helping me.

I tried my codes but it doesn't punch the number that i was expecting. it was blank. in short it my code won't work.

Comment: What is *autopunch*? Where are these functions coming from?

Comment: it is just my term. What i meant on my question is that D1_1 is dropdown question. If he select option 1 the next question which is hD1_1 will put an answer "1923" in the textbox or numeric box